# What is considered a "review" in github?

Tags: github

I'm trying to use this query in github Pull Requests:

`is:pr is:open  review:none`

However, it matches PRs such as `https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen++-label%3Astale+draft%3Afalse+review%3Anone+`, which shows a Reviewer having made comments:

[image]

In fact, if I go to another one in the list (https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/pull/12067), the "Conversation" tab shows one person having "reviewed" and "commented". Another person "left a comment".

Note that these are even people who have merge permission on the repo.

By the way, I can tell that `review:none` is doing something, as it reduces the number of results returned.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that only "Approve" and "Request changes" are considered to be reviews by this filter. "Comment" does not constitute a review. I find this to be unexpected behavior.